# Why does :s command regex not understand '?'

Tags: vim, sed

When you try to remove html tags from a line, one possible way of doing it, is to use the :s command and write a regex that understands the beginning and the end of a tag at the same time. My go for it was:

```
:s %</?center>%%g
```

But this way, vim says it doesn't find anything. So I had to use the following instead, which worked:

```
:s %</*center>%%g
```

Why is that one works but the other doesn't? Shouldn't `?` say "the character before can come once or maybe not at all"?

Comment: `:help magic` for you (:help pattern.txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `?` with `\`.

Refer help-page:

```
:h pattern-overview
```

Comment: Why are you saying that? `?` haven't to be escaped if you want to use it as a wildcard

Comment: +1 Don't know who downvoted this but this is the correct info here :)

Comment: @DonCallisto, unless you use verymagic, ? will match a literal ?. Vim regex is pretty confusing in this way. I personally always prepend every pattern with `\v`.

Comment: That is the correct answer and the reference to the correct help. If possible I would give +2.

Comment: There is also the idiomatic Vim-specific [`\=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\=) pattern. It matches the same as `\?` with the minor advantage that you can use it in a regex that starts with `?`.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't the same.

> The ? (question mark) matches the preceding character **0 or 1 times
>   only**, for example, colou?r will find both color (0 times) and colour
>   (1 time).
>
> The * (asterisk or star) matches the preceding character **0 or more
>      times**, for example, tre* will find tree (2 times) and tread (1 time)
>      and trough (0 times).

Can you give us the matches that will be substituted?

Moreover, i know that this kind of operation is done with that command `s/foo/bar/g` that will substitute every occurency of `foo` with `bar`

Comment: It is a very good explanation, but doesn't connect to the question at all. I think it might be helpful for future readers anyway -> up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `?` like this to have to use vim's `very magic` regex mode (`\v`), however this also interprets `<` and `>` as word boundaries so now they need to be escaped:

```
:%s,\v\</?center\>,,g
```

The shorter option here, as you have discovered, is to escape the `?`:

```
:%s,</\?center>,,g
```

See `:help /magic` for more.

Comment: I have to say with my comment there is at least a little mistake on my part. I didn't see for whatever reason, that you need to add the `\v` at first. So I tried it again with the `\v` but it still doesn't work perfectly. From the input `<center>abc</center>` I expect to get `abc` but I get now `<>abc</>`. The escaping works fine though and escaping the `?` is less code then adding `\v`, so I think it won't be a problem.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, my answer is only partially correct, I'll fix it shortly.